# Directive generate directive field dynamically does not compile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have created basic **HTML** field generator directive called **field** as like below

```
app.directive('field',function(){
        return {
            restrict : "E",
            scope : {
               fielddata : '='
            },
            link : function(scope,elem,attr){
                var content;
                scope.Options = {
                    id: scope.$id+'_'+elem.attr('id'),
                    label : elem.attr('label'),
                    placeholder : elem.attr("placeholder"),

                };
                scope.contentUrl = 'templates/fields/'+elem.attr('template')+'.html';           
            },
            template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>'
        }
    })
```

I can able to generate fields as like below

```
<field id="NAME" template="text" label="First Name" placeholder="Enter First Name" fieldData="NAME"></field>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ako1jjdv9VdKgWyFEDxY?p=preview)

Extending the functionality to generate  element directive itself. Have simple object to setup the **field** element and use another directive to generate  element directive

**Controller**

```
app.controller('contactController', ['$scope', 'dataService',function($scope,dataService) {
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! . This is just a demo.';
        dataService.getContactData().then(function(data) {
            $scope.NAME = data.first_name;
            $scope.LNAME = data.last_name;
            $scope.DESC = data.description;
        });
          $scope.fields= [
            {
              elements: [
                            {
                                template_name : "text"
                                id: "NAME",
                                label: "First Name",
                                placeholder : "First Name"
                            }           
                        ],
              html: '<div ng-repeat="elem in t.elements"><field id="{{elem.id}}" template="{{elem.template_name}}" label="{{elem.label}}"  placeholder="{{elem.placeholder}}""  fieldData="{{elem.id}}" ></field></div>'
            }
          ];
    }]);
    app.directive("bindCompiledHtml", function($compile, $timeout) {
      return {
        template: '<div></div>',
        scope: {
          rawHtml: '=bindCompiledHtml'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('rawHtml', function(value) {
            if (!value) return;
            var newElem = $compile(value)(scope.$parent);
            elem.contents().remove();
            elem.append(newElem);
          });
        }
      };
    });
});
```

Say **contact.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="t in fields" bind-compiled-html="t.html"></div>
```

My issue is, **bindCompiledHtml** Directive generate  elements and calling **field** directive as expected but it value is not get parsed. Setting Break point from field directive link function gives **elem** as below

```
[
<field id=​"{{elem.id}​}​" template=​"{{elem.template_name}​}​" label=​"{{elem.label}​}​" placeholder=​"{{elem.placeholder}​}​" class=​"ng-isolate-scope">​
<!-- ngInclude: contentUrl -->
</field>​
]
```

and console gives following error

```
/templates/fields/%7B%7Belem.template_name%7D%7D.html 404 (Not Found)
```

To see 404 Please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7Zzm0Km4R3x93i3g5nI?p=preview) console

How do we call **field** directive once all its value get parsed with isolate scope ? Please advice

Comment: Can you specify the initial problem you're solving? Are you trying to have pages with dynamic content where you can "switch on/off" blocks that are defined in multiple templates with parameters?

Comment: @KirillSlatin I am trying to generate field using custom directive. Initially i tried with field directive which render dynamic HTML fields based on <field> directive attrs.Now i wanted to generated dynamic field directive itself using 'bindCompiledHtml', here it generate dynamic <field> and called <field> directive before it get parsed.since value is not get parsed , template url goes 404.please advice

Comment: @KirillSlatin Did u get the issue?

Comment: What is the expected behavior of your plunker code?

Comment: @KirillSlatin Aim is bindCompiledHtml directive should generate <field> element which then convert text box by field directive.but fails now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dinesh, without a given original problem your code is rather over complicated. That is why I was asking about the purposes of these nested compilations.

The trouble you experience in current code is the definition of directive. Once it's attributes are not defined in isolated scope via `=` their values will never be *evaluated* and will always remain plain text. That is why you can't use expressions in `ng-repeat` like `{{t.template_name}}` when you define values for attributes of your `field` directive. Directive should have the following implementation

```
app.directive('field', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      placeholder: '=',
      label: '=',
      id: '=',
      template: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var content;
      scope.Options = {
        id: scope.$id + '_' + scope.id,
        label: scope.label,
        placeholder: scope.placeholder
      };
      scope.contentUrl = scope.template + '.html';
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>'
  }
});
```

As a result you will *always* have to define an expression to these attributes. Thus in 'manual' markup you would use `"'my text'"` instead of `"my text"`

```
<field id="NAME" template="'text'" label="'First Name'" 
     max-size="40" placeholder="'Enter First Name'" 
     type="edit" ></field>
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RIDYldGt38FgecGRoKWS?p=preview)

Comment: from bindCompiledHtml directive fieldData="elem.id" gives      its id as value.From my controller factory service i assigned $scope.NAME = data.first_name; it does not prepopulate the ajax data instead it pre populate its id as value.

Comment: check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3YdxamEHNGKGKQGi7ypJ?p=preview bindCompiledHtml directive  should get data from json instead it is showing ID

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question? in this case many people will be able to see it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973710/dynamic-directive-element-fails-in-pre-populate-data-from-service