# Dynamic Directive element fails in Pre populate data from service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Found some solution to create dynamic fields by directive using object.Also can able to create dynamic directive

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('field', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      placeholder: '=',
      label: '=',
      id: '=',
      fielddata: '=',
      template: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
       scope.Options = {
        id: scope.$id + '_' + scope.id,
        label: scope.label,
        placeholder: scope.placeholder
      };
      scope.contentUrl = scope.template + '.html';
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>'
  }
});
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3YdxamEHNGKGKQGi7ypJ?p=preview)

Dynamic directive, generate fields as expected but its value is not getting pre populate by ajax service as expected in separate field.Instead it is gives ID  as its value.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect it to display? in your `Ctrl1` controller you define such a dynamic template:

```
html: '<div ng-repeat="elem in t.elements"><field id="elem.id" fieldData="elem.id" label="elem.label" template="elem.template_name" placeholder="elem.placeholder"></field></div>'
```

Mind the `fieldData="elem.id"` attribute. Your `field` directive is displaying value provided via `fielddata` attribute. And you do provide element's `id` for it.

Comment: Since we already used fieldData as ng-model in text.html template and used as isolate scope in field directive.I am expecting, generated field should hold value from ajax data.

Comment: Correct but you should insert AJAX data into `$scope.fields.elements` array (let's say `ajaxField`) and further use it as a value in your html template in `Ctrl1`, for example `feildData="elem.ajaxField"`

Comment: If it was helpful, please, mark the answer as solved, to indicate for future readers. If solution described wasn't complete let me know how to update the text to include all changes required

Comment: I have given plunker based on your comment .So please check once plunker and update ur answer :)